# the attribute value is not getting

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i declare attribute on

```js
<a href="#"  data-hasloaded='0'">
```

i want this value of data-hasloaded in a variable i use this code

```js
 var hasloaded=$(this).attr('data-hasloaded');
```

but the value is getting as undefined .

Comment: show your full code

Comment: what is the context of `this` ?

Comment: var myVal = $(this).data('hasloaded');

Comment: try `var hasloaded=$(this).data("hasloaded');` but without full code, we can't confirm that `$(this)` is a tag

Comment: @PunitGajjar even `var hasloaded=$(this).attr('data-hasloaded');` should work

Comment: data-hasloaded='0'" remove the " double quote.
In the second example include jquery maybe? Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: $(this).data('hasloaded') is equivalent to $(this).attr('data-hasloaded'). The problem is obviously the the binding of this, not whether he's using .data() or .attr().

Comment: @YoYo He did not mention how he wanna access his variable  by id or by class or by what ,,  so it was a very confusing for us.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<a href="#"  data-hasloaded='0'" id="dataId">

var hasloaded=$("#dataId").attr('data-hasloaded');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hasloaded=$('a').attr('data-hasloaded');
alert(hasloaded)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"  data-hasloaded='0'>
```